PostGres - Get top 5 frequent values in each column from a table
My table can have 100s of columns.
It is not necessary that we need 5 rows. We could also have a single row, where the values are concatenated.
I can select top 5 frequent values from a single column using the below query
SELECT col1 FROM table GROUP BY col1 ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 5

But I want top 5 frequent values from every column. I am trying to use WITH clauses, like.
WITH top_5_col1 AS (
    SELECT col1 FROM table GROUP BY col1 ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 5
),
top_5_col2 AS (
    SELECT col2 FROM table GROUP BY col2 ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 5
)
SELECT 
    STRING_AGG(top_5_col1.col1, ','::text) as col1,
    STRING_AGG(top_5_col2.col2, ','::text) as col2
FROM top_5_col1, top_5_col2;

There could be 100s of columns.
What would be a better way to achieve it?

If you mean a better way to achieve it without repeating the code 100 times, then you can use PL/pgSQL to loop over information_schema.columns and for each column in the target table, use dynamic SQL execute to repeat that select. If you're looking for a way to get the histogram faster because you're monitoring the table frequently, you'd have to set up tally tables and triggers to maintain them. Also, 100s of columns usually means there's room for normalisation, and the table could be split up into smaller ones, which are faster to process.

You could also peek the most_common_vals in pg_stats, if your table statistics are up to date.

It's better to write a function like this
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pizza_runner.f_count_top5(table_name varchar, column_name varchar, schema_name varchar)
 RETURNS text
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare 
ret text;
    begin
        EXECUTE format('select STRING_AGG(%1$s, '',''::text) as %1$s from (SELECT %1$s FROM %2$s.%3$s GROUP BY %1$s ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 5) q1'
            , column_name
            , schema_name
            , table_name) into ret;
        return ret;
    END;
$function$
;

And after use it to count top 5 values using information_schema
   select column_name, f_count_top5(table_name::varchar, column_name::varchar, table_schema::varchar) from 
    information_schema.columns
    where "columns".table_schema = 'pizza_runner' and table_name = 't1'

This query returns result like this
 column_name|f_count_top5  |
    -----------+--------------+
    col1       |16,22,25,23,15|
    col2       |24,7,15,21,2  |
    col3       |24,4,5,10,19  |
    col4       |23,16,21,24,9 |
    col5       |5,19,12,24,21 |
    col6       |5,13,0,10,1   |
    col7       |10,19,9,21,1  |
    col8       |7,12,10,13,25 |
    col9       |12,19,4,9,1   |
    col10      |6,13,21,5,19  |



If you're not using placeholders (%s, %I, %L), you can execute without format(). 2. You can replace thte mile-long sequence of || with format() and use placeholders to inject the column_name. A concat() or concat_ws() could also make things shorter.
You can return execute t_sql; without assigning it to anything. You can also return execute format()directly, without assigning that tot_sqlvariable, too, saving you the entiredeclare` part.


I made code improvements according to your notes, but I cant make return execute format()... Can you show how It can be done?

Thanks. It worked. Have used some of the suggestions from @Zegarek as well.

@AlexTank demo - I forgot that's only for set-returning functions, so that'd be return query execute format(), which isn't allowed for scalars - but you can have an SRF that returns a single value by design. It's best to use %I for identifiers to make sure you get quoting wherever it's necessary.
